# Prove that if $∑_{n=1}^∞b_n$ converges then $∑_{n=1}^∞a_n$ converges.

Tags: calculus

Let $∑_{n=1}^∞a_n$  and $∑_{n=1}^∞b_n$  be series of positive terms satisfying $a_{n+1}/a_n ≤b_{n+1}/b_n$ . Prove that if $∑_{n=1}^∞b_n$ converges then $∑_{n=1}^∞a_n$  converges.

here is my thoughts. I intend to let $c_n =\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and $d_n = \frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}$, from this I have $c_n \leq d_n$. Using the comparison test I have $∑_{n=1}^∞d_n$ converges implies $∑_{n=1}^∞c_n$  converges. However I'm not sure that this can help me, can't it?

Comment: [Ratio test?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)

Comment: I haven't learn this yet, this problem is in comparison test and integral test section.

Comment: Your terms must be positive. Take $a_n = (-1)^n$ and $b_n = 1/n^2$ as a counterexample.

Comment: yes, they are both defined as series of positive terms

Comment: @nayrb it is written in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove by induction that
$$a_{n} \leq b_n \frac{a_1}{b_1}$$
(or rather, just note that $a_n/b_n$ is decreasing to establish the above).
Then use the comparison test.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit. Nice answer.

Comment: I think it was only valid when n is sufficiently large. Please see my answer below, and also explain your reasoning why {$a_n/b_n$} is decreasing for all n.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy test (i.e. partial sum of a convergent series form a Cauchy sequence), $$\forall\; 0\lt \varepsilon \lt 1, \exists N \in \mathbb N \; \text{such that}\; \forall n\ge N, |b_n+b_{n+1}|\lt \varepsilon$$

Since $b_k \gt 0 \;\forall k, b_{n+1}-b_n\lt |b_n+b_{n+1}|\lt \varepsilon$

Then $\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}-1 \lt \dfrac{\varepsilon}{b_n}$, so $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \lt 1+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{b_n}\lt 1$ i.e. both {$a_n$} and {$b_n$} are monotonic decreasing from the Nth term onwards.

Thus we have $a_{n+1}\lt a_n + \dfrac{a_n \varepsilon}{b_n}\lt a_n + \dfrac{a_n }{b_n} \;\forall n\ge N$. Notice that $\dfrac{a_n}{b_n} \ge \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} \forall n$, so $a_{n+1} \lt a_n + \dfrac{a_n }{b_n}\le  a_n + \dfrac{a_m}{b_m}\;\forall n\ge N, m\le n$

And therefore, $0\lt \dfrac{a_n }{b_n}\le  \dfrac{a_m}{b_m}\lt 1$  i.e. {$\dfrac{a_n }{b_n}$} is monotonic decreasing and bounded.

We then have $a_n \le b_n \dfrac{a_N}{b_N}$. Notice that here $\dfrac{a_N}{b_N}$ is a constant with $0 \lt \dfrac{a_N}{b_N} \lt 1$, so by comparison test,  $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$ converges.